# solving a linear diophantine equation in two variables

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm a bit confused in applying the Euclidean algorithm to solve the following equation:

$$11x + 34 = 13y + 35$$

$$x,y\in\Bbb Z; \qquad0 < x,y$$

How can I go about solving it, if there are solutions?

Comment: Have a look at the *extended* Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply Euclids algorithm to $11$ and $13$
\begin{eqnarray*}
13-11=2 \\
11-5 \times 2 =1.
\end{eqnarray*}
So
\begin{eqnarray*}
1=11-5 \times 2 =11 -5(13-11)=\color{blue}{6}\times 11  \color{red}{-5}\times 13
\end{eqnarray*}
and hence you have values for $\color{blue}{x}$ and $\color{red}{y}$.

The general solution is $\color{blue}{x=6+13k}$ and $\color{red}{y=-5-11k}$.

Answer (score 1):

$11x - 13 y = 1$

$$  \gcd( 13, 11 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 13 }{ 11 } = 1 +  \frac{ 2 }{ 11 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 11 }{ 2 } = 5 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 2 }{ 1 } = 2 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccc}
 & & 1 & & 5 & & 2 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }   & &   \frac{ 13 }{ 11 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
 $$ 13 \cdot 5 - 11 \cdot 6 = -1 $$

But you want
$11 \cdot 6 - 13 \cdot 5 = 1$ which is true, $66-65$